# Where is the Tomcat dir that comes with netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have installed netbeans 7.1 that comes pre-bundeled with `Tomcat`. I need to find the `context.xml` in the tomcat. Where is tomcat directory located in netbeans ? Where can i find `context.xml`

[image]

Comment: why don't you just search 'tomcat' with windows?

Comment: @ftom2 because the answer by @ sakhti is a better approach ! Hoe you **understand** _this_

Comment: Somebody got up on the wrong side of bed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Netbeans,go to
Tools --> Servers --> you will get server details.

you will find "Context.xml" in following location

/tomcat home folder path/conf

Comment: What if there was no Tomcat there? I actually had a previous version of Netbeans 7.0.1 and already had Tomcat 7.0.14. Now I installed the new Netbeans 8.2 (all) which comes with Tomcat 8.0.27 but I don't see Tomcat 8.0.27 anywhere. I was able to add in the old Tomcat 7.0.14 to my Netbeans servers list, but it gives me lots of access denied errors for log files and warnings about work directories when I try to start it.